# Carregar combobox C# a partir de outro no Load()

Tags: c#, winforms

Faz tanto tempo que não trabalhava com WinForms que estou deixando passar algo.
No Load do meu Form eu chamo esse método abaixo:

```
private void CarregarEstados()
{
    cboEstado.DataSource = Listas.ListaEstados();
    cboEstado.DisplayMember = "UF";
}

public static DataTable ListaEstados()
{
    DataTable _table = null;

    try
    {
        var _connector = GetSQLInstance.getInstance();
        _table = _connector.GetTable(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "SPL_CREDENCIADOS_UF_PESQUISA");
    }
    catch (Exception Error)
    {
        LastErrorCode = MazeFire.ErrorManager.GetErrorCode(Error);
        LastErrorObject = Error;
        LastError = Error.Message;
    }

    return _table;
}
```

O método chamado retorna um DataTable com uma coluna chamada UF.
Ele carrega o combo sem problemas.

Porém, me foi pedido para eu carregar automaticamente as Cidades e Bairros que estão disponíveis no BD. Então, faço isso no evento abaixo:

```
private void cboEstado_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Assim o Combo sempre retorna vazio
    CarregarCidades(cboEstado.SelectedText);
}

private void CarregarCidades(string estado)
{
    cboCidade.DataSource = Listas.ListaCidades(estado);
    cboCidade.DisplayMember = "Cidade";
}
```

Meu problema ocorre ao chamar o CarregarCidades, pois não consigo obter o valor setado no cboEstado (no caso SP).
Aí no exemplo está como `cboEstado.SelectedText` que passa "" para o método, mas já tentei `cboEstado.SelectedValue.ToString()` e `cboEstado.SelectedItem.ToString()` e ambos passam `System.Data.DataRowView` como parâmetro.

Poderiam me explicar o que estou deixando passar?

Obrigado.

Comment: E o seu método `Listas.ListaCidades(estado);`? Como está?

Comment: Vou editar acima.. Coloquei o ListaEstado.. o ListaCidade e o ListaBairro são iguais em estrutura

Comment: @DanielAfonso, Não é necessário você colocar resolvido no título da pergunta. E não é correto você apresentar a sua resposta nela também. Se você deve aceitar uma das propostas como reposta ou postar a sua solução como uma resposta e marcar ela mesmo.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo desculpe por isso! Sou novo aqui e ainda estou entendendo como funciona. Vou corrigir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom dia, Daniel Afonso. 
Acredito que teu problema esteja no fato de que ao trabalhar com o evento `Combobox.SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e)`, a propriedade `ComboBox.SelectedText()` vem sempre como string vazia. O certo é trabalhar com `ComboBox.SelectedItem()`.

O ComboBox é um componente que trabalha com um dicionário de entradas que são exibidas na lista suspensa, e cada entrada possui um objeto relacionado.

Quando preenchemos o ComboBox com tipos nativos de valor (string, int, bool, etc), a lista é preenchida com entradas 1 para 1, onde o conteúdo da lista suspensa é o `(objeto_referido).ToString()`. Agora, quando preenchemos o ComboBox com tipos de referência (objetos), ai tem-se que determinar qual propriedade do objeto será a sua entrada na lista suspensa. Quando um determinado item da lista, for selecionado, a propriedade `ComboBox.SelectedItem()` vai retornar a referência aquele objeto, e não a entrada da lista.

> mas já tentei cboEstado.SelectedValue.ToString() e cboEstado.SelectedItem.ToString() e ambos passam System.Data.DataRowView

Isso acontece porque você está tentando obter uma conversão explicita para string de um tipo (Data.DataRowView) que não tem uma implementação dessa função. Quando isso acontece, o dotnet simplesmente retorna o "caminho completo" do tipo do objeto.

**Solução no seu código**

Existiriam um milhão de aproximações possíveis para contornar isso, mas eu acho que a mais fácil seria obter na chamada da função `CarregarCidades(string)`, trocar o parâmetro `cboEstado.SelectedText()` por `(cboEstado.SelectedItem).Row.Item["UF"].ToString()`.

**Fontes**

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext?view=netframework-4.7.2

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowview?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowview.row?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataRowView_Row

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo detalhado esclarecimento sobre o funcionamento do controle. Vou dar uma olhada nas referências que me mandou e no exemplo. ;)

Comment: Usando seu exemplo deu erro no SelectedItem, pois não pode ser usado como método. Mas seguindo sua explicação e dicas, consegui resolver. Vou postar na pergunta principal, pois poderá ajudar alguém tbm. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado por já me corrigir também. Vou alterar aqui também para ficar conciso e não confuso.

Comment: @UmbertoSantos Coloque a sua solução implementada no código do autor da pergunta, talvez assim ele aceite como resposta